# Accessing Button on KV file when its defined in a Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to change the background color of the button in my KV file but it doesnt work. the button was defined and loop from the Python file

```
def gotoPost(i, instance):
    print("HAHAHAH")
    Manager.current = 'ScreenTwo'

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    box = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_box(self, *args):
        for i in range(5):
            btn = Button(text=str(i))
            btn.bind(on_press=partial(gotoPost,i))
            self.box.add_widget(btn)

Factory.register('ScreenOne', cls=ScreenOne)

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):

    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()
if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

How do i access the button in the KV file?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    box = ObjectProperty(None)
    color = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
    back_color = [0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
    def on_box(self, *args):
        for i in range(5):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), color= self.color, background_color= self.back_color)
            btn.bind(on_press=partial(gotoPost,i))
            self.box.add_widget(btn)
```

You can assign a button to change the color as needed when pressed. Ex: self.color or self.back_color = (7,0,1,1)... I think that's red

Comment: The question is "How do i access the button in the KV file?" and not in Python script.